# Python service similar to rpyc.Service but only local

Tags: python, rpyc

A very naive question...

I need to have a central Python program offering services to other Python applications (all running on the same machine). The easiest for me would be that the other applications could directly call functions provided by the server. I know [rpyc](https://rpyc.readthedocs.org) (Remote Python Call) and the `rpyc.Service` class could do the job (like in [this tutorial](http://rpyc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/tut3.html#tut3)]) but I do not want anything "remote" (all clients have to be local, running on the same machine as the server) so I was wondering if there was a better way to do this than using rpyc?

Comment: when you say "I do not want anything remote" you mean no remote _objects_?

Comment: A server can be running on the same machine as the clients.

Comment: Yes a rpyc server can be running on the same machine as the clients but rpyc is too powerful for what I want since a remote client could connect to the server and ask for services.